# My app images taking too much time to load which i am retrieving from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

my flutter app taking much time to load images. in carousel view after loading images it is loading again. how can i resolve this? ----  **see below attached video**

[my app video recording link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ojOlzILx6rKVhXpxa9brIlNN8Wfm0NPf/view?usp=sharing)

pls help if you know it will be help me a lot

Comment: Compress image before you upload to firebase.

Comment: thank you but how any package or something else??

Comment: You can use [flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress)

Comment: @Hemal please consider posting your solution as the answer to this thread. It will help other community members who have the same question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

---

I searched everywhere but everyone tells about how to read and write into storage but no one told that what is the right process. Thanks to @Hemal for giving me a hint. I think it will be helpful for every freshers.

---

### **Solution:**

Every time when you store image or video into storage, do **compress** so that you can retrieve data fast & even your daily Bandwidth will be spend few.

Comment: Can you please share the way with me because I search a lot and I did not find anything

Comment: I actually use the image networks :(